# Error "Unable to load type WebApi.WebApiApplication" when running WebApi project in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi

When I tried run my WebApi project I got this error:

> Server error in application '/'. Analyzer error Description: An error
>   occurred while retrieving the resource required to serve this request.
>   Please refer to the following specific retirement error information
>   and change the source file accordingly.
>
> Analyzer error message: Unable to load type
>   'WebApi.WebApiApplication'.
>
> Source error:
>
> Line 1: <% @ Application Codebehind = "Global.asax.cs" Inherits =
>   "WebApi.WebApiApplication" Language = "C #"%>
>
> Source file: /global.asax Line: 1
>
> Version data: Microsoft .NET Framework version: 4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET:4.7.2556.0 version

**The global.asax**

```
  public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, DELETE, PUT,POST");
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Pragma, Cache-Control, Authorization ");

            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: add the code what you write code

Comment: Does your app actually compile?

Comment: yes. my app actually compile